# Unix HP-UX ksh recursive find and replace

Tags: unix, sed, find, ksh, hp-ux

I am trying to do a recursive find and replace in HP-UX and am missing something.

What I have at the moment:

```
find . -name "*.java" | xargs sed 's/foo/bar/g'
```

know the problem is that it's not replacing the file inline. I believe on other OS's there is a -i flag, but it seems in my HP-UX version, there isn't.

Any suggestions?

Comment: check here:http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/find-and-replace-string-in-all-files.html

Comment: Also asked on Superuser: http://superuser.com/q/532573/4714

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -name "*.java" | xargs sed -i 's/foo/bar/g'
```

or

```
find . -name "*.java" | xargs perl -pi -e's/foo/bar/g'
```

Comment: As mentioned, the -i flag doesn't work with my version of sed. The second option worked however. Thanks.

Comment: Even on my solaris -i is not available for sed .so i too use perl.but on a whole its the only way where sed does the replace in place.

Comment: Note that the above will fail for file names that contain spaces (or some other characters). You'd need to use `find -print0` and `xargs -0` to get around that but -0 isn't available with xargs on Solaris and I don't think -print0 is available with find either.

Answer (score 1):

The simple, portable solution to run any tool you like on the files and change them "in-place" (sed -i uses a tmp file behind the scenes too) is just:

```
find . -name "*.java" |
while IFS= read -r file; do
   sed 's/foo/bar/g' "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file"
done
```

You can use that approach for sed, grep, cut, whatever you like:

```
find . -name "*.java" |
while IFS= read -r file; do
   grep "whatever" "$file" > tmp && mv tmp "$file"
done
```

The only thing that won't work on is files whose names contain newlines but nor would the `find | xargs` solution as-is and you should rename those if you have them anyway.